# How can I prevent browsers from using default styles

Tags: css, cross-browser

All the browsers apply their own default styling to html elements. That leads to difference of views on different browsers. Is there any way to prevent browsers from doing this?

Comment: Look into using a css reset; http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Modern browsers use a fairly similar default style sheet these days.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, you need to use [`CSS Reset`](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), this will generalize the styles, in other words it will reset the styles across the browsers.

Personally I don't use these, instead I use the snippet below which is more than enough for me.

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   outline: 0;
}
```

If you want to stabilize more elements, you can make your own, like you can use the below to have pointer cursor when a user hovers any button or link on your website..Yes now that's pretty basic User Experience, than you can use

```
button, a, input[type=button], input[type=submit] {
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

Or say don't underline the links and inherit the parent color, so I use

```
a {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: inherit;
}
```

This way you can make your own, I prefer this way.

---

Just a side note, when I go responsive, I change the `*` snippet to

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   outline: 0;   
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

---

> Note: Using Reset Stylesheet won't reset any inheritance, it will only
>   reset browser defaults(which won't help you always to make cross
>   browser websites) but will prevent loads of cross browsers issues commonly like `padding`, `margin`, `line-height`, base font etc.

Comment: Exactly. And if you want to go báck to the browser default (as if no CSS rule was applied), you can in the future use the CSS rule "* { all: default; }" (CSS3 specific)

Comment: Supportive link for the comment above http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/#all-shorthand

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into [**Normalize.css**](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/). It;s used by a large number of frameworks and other reset boilerplates.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for reset.css. This should be the first one to be applied to reset any browser specific style..
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/

Comment: Can you please tell me how this is better than the CSS Reset?